# Computer beeps during Maven build

Tags: maven, build, console, maven-3, beep

I have encountered this before, but ignored it, as the problem was on a pet project of mine and I was willing to tolerate it. Now this started happening at work and I can't find anyone else on the Internet complaining of this.

When I run a Maven build, there are certain unit tests that make the computer issue "beep"s. I am sorry I can't really provide much more info on what I am doing wrong, as I am clueless. I think it's the unit tests that do some I/O. I think it could also be somehow caused by the logging framework. It could be neither of the two guesses.

There are guides on the internet showing me how to disable the beep but I don't want to cure the symptom, rather understand (and remove) the cause.

Surely there are people out there who have experienced the same and could drop a note here with what this turned out to be or how they dealt with it. Any hints/pointers welcome.

Comment: +1 Great question. :) Maybe it because `\a` (bell character) is being printed into the console.

Comment: *Computer beeps* it reminded me of `C` days... looping through `char`-s. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has never happened to me with Maven or unit testing but if you say it maybe related to  I/O or/and logging framework then it could be the `\a` - [`Bell character`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_character) being printed in the console.

Comment: You hit the spot! I found the call that does the logging of some Italian copy text and wrapped it in a loop. That started to beep furiously. So it is that logging call indeed. The copy text must contain the bell character and that gets logged to the console during maven build. I will look into configuring logging for my tests to avoid printing out the copy test into console. Excellent! Thanks!